# Formula in JS to create experience goals for different branches in a game

Tags: javascript, math, formula, game-development

I'm creating a little game in Javascript, and I have trees that can hold a certain amount of max experience, and each tree have a varied amount of branches that also needs to be leveled up with experience, and they should total to the tree max experience.

If it was that easy, I would just divide them equally, like `max / branches`, but since it's for a game, I need to make a formula where the first branch needs no experience, and then each branch experience needed steadily increase (while still totalling to the tree max experience).

```
Branch 1              0 XP
Branch 2              100 XP
Branch 3              200 XP
Branch 4              300 XP

Total Tree Experience Capacity: 600 XP
```

The amount of branches can be anything from 2 to 10, to 20 and so on, so it must therefor scale with the tree max experience capacity, I believe. How much I want each level to increase with must also depend on how many branches there are, but there should be some kind of pattern across all trees, I think (correct me if it's a bad idea).

The variables that we know are:

- The amount of branches we have per tree
- Max experience capacity for each tree

The rest is unknown.

How can a formula solve this issue? I also do not mind any functional formulas for specifically JS.

Comment: Do you want to work out the arithmetic progression by its sum and members?

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, I suppose that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: OK, I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seem to want is [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression). It's a sequence of numbers where there is a common difference between each, for example `1, 4, 7, 10` would be an arithmetic progression where the difference is `3` between each subsequent members.

The more generalised view of arithmetic progression is

```
a, a + d, a + 2d, a + 3d, ..., a + nd`
```

Where `a` is your *initial member*, `d` is the *difference*, and `n` is the *length* of the series.

The formula for a sum of arithmetic series is as follows:

```
S = (n/2) * (2*a + (n - 1)*d)
```

Which looks complex let's just see it in action. Let's say we want to sum the series `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`. Or integers from 1 to 10. Substituting in the formula, we have `a = 1`, `d = 1`, `n = 10` and we get

```
S = (10/2) * (2*1 + (10 - 1)*1)
  = 5 * (2 + 9*1)
  = 5 * (2 + 9)
  = 5 * 11
  = 55
```

And we can just write code to verify:

```js
const sum = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10;

console.log(sum);
```

So, the formula works.

Now, we want to shuffle things - we have `S`, for the *total tree experience capacity*, we also have `n` the *number of branches*, and we have `a` which would be zero for the initial branch. We just need to find `d` in order to get all the things we need. So, here it goes:

```
S = (n/2) * (2*a + (n - 1)*d)
S / (n/2) = 2*a + (n - 1)*d
(S / (n/2)) - 2*a = (n - 1)*d
((S / (n/2)) - 2*a) / (n - 1) = d
```

We can actually eliminate `2*a` since we know `a = 0`, so we can slightly simplify the formula:

```
(S / (n/2)) / (n - 1) = d
```

And done. We can just encode it in a function now:

```js
// S = totalExperience
// n = branches

function findArithmeticStep(totalExperience, branches) {
  return (totalExperience / (branches/2)) / (branches - 1);
}

console.log(findArithmeticStep(600, 4));
```

You can even use a generator function that will supply you the next XP value:

```js
// S = totalExperience
// n = branches

function findArithmeticStep(totalExperience, branches) {
  return (totalExperience / (branches/2)) / (branches - 1);
}

function* nextXPCost(totalExperience, branches) {
  const step = findArithmeticStep(totalExperience, branches);
  
  let currentXPCost = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < branches; i++) {
    yield currentXPCost;
    currentXPCost += step;
  }
}

const gen = nextXPCost(600, 4);

//1 - 0
let next = gen.next();
console.log(next.value, next.done);
//2 - 100
next = gen.next();
console.log(next.value, next.done);
//3 - 200
next = gen.next();
console.log(next.value, next.done);
//4 - 300
next = gen.next();
console.log(next.value, next.done);
//5 - getting after the end
next = gen.next();
console.log(next.value, next.done);

//generate an array of all costs
const allCostsTree1 = [...nextXPCost(600, 4)];
console.log(allCostsTree1);


//generate a different tree with higher total cost
const allCostsTree2 = [...nextXPCost(2000, 5)];
console.log(allCostsTree2)
```

Comment: Very thorough answer and interesting approach, the generator function is especially helpful (and cool!). It definetely worked to solve my problem with the formula, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This is what you seek.

Your "rate" increment for each level is based on the summation of all the numbers between "1" and the BRANCH_COUNT-1.  There's probably a name in mathematics for this summatation, but I forget it....

It's easily computed with a simple function that takes the total number of branches and the total XP.

```
// A function that determines the rate by which each branch reward should increment by
function getRate(branch_count, total_xp) {
   if (branch_count <= 1) {
        return 0;
   }

   let R = 0;

   for (let i = 1; i < branch_count; i++) {
      R += i;
   }

   return total_xp / R;
}
```

And by recalling some high school match [as explained here](https://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Sum-of-an-Arithmetic-Sequence). The above is can be simplified to just this:

```
function getRate(branch_count, total_xp) {
   if (branch_count <= 1) {
        return 0;
   }

   let R = ((branch_count-1) * (branch_count))/2;
   return total_xp / R;
}
```

And then some sample code using that function to print out the reward structure for each branch

```
// sample function to print the reward count for each branch 
function dumpBranches(branch_count, total_xp) {

    let rate = getRate(branch_count, total_xp);
    let reward = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < branch_count; i++) {
        console.log("Branch ", i, reward);
        reward += rate;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
> dumpBranches(4, 600)
Branch  0 0
Branch  1 100
Branch  2 200
Branch  3 300

> dumpBranches(9, 2700)
Branch  0 0
Branch  1 75
Branch  2 150
Branch  3 225
Branch  4 300
Branch  5 375
Branch  6 450
Branch  7 525
Branch  8 600
```